# How do I find who handled a message on a specific date based on employee's timesheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google sheet that's automatically populates when a certain event happens. It updates with a timestamp & event description. But I want to look up who was working during that time, based on timesheets out of Hubstaff.

My timesheet export out of Hubstaff is formatted like this:

```
|Start of Shift         |End of shift            |Employee
|8/14/2021 10:37:50     |8/14/2021 16:00:33      |Employee 1
|8/14/2021 22:21:28     |8/15/2021 0:00:00       |Employee 1
|8/15/2021 0:00:00      |8/15/2021 4:05:01       |Employee 1
|8/15/2021 4:10:00      |8/15/2021 8:05:01       |Employee 2
```

I want to look up the employee who was active during the event of the log. So the desired output is:

```
|Event time                  |Employee
|8/14/2021 20:15:00          |BLANK <- as nobody was working
|8/15/2021 0:20:00           |Employee 1
|8/15/2021 4:58:00           |Employee 2
```

I've been trying to figure it out, but I can't seem to pinpoint how to do it exactly. Has anybody had any experience with similar situations?

Comment: here is a blank sheet, generated specifically for this question.  Paste enough sample data there that would be necessary to create the table you're looking for and provide some "desired results" based on that data.  This will make it easier for people to understand your question and give answers that you're able to use:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dyOHqrmjV8sj_CyPPJYUwmDbMmgnfdiD6RQKE59ubfc/edit

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

You can try this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(
    IFERROR(MATCH(H1:H3,FLATTEN($A$2:$B$5),0),0)+
            (MOD(MATCH(H1:H3,FLATTEN($A$2:$B$5),1),2)=1),
    VLOOKUP(H1:H3,
           {FLATTEN($A$2:$B$5),FLATTEN(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(REPT(concat($C$2:$C$5," "),2)," ")))}
           ,2,TRUE
           ),
    "BLANK"
  )
)
```

**Explanation:**

I created a "helper" table using this segment, this would be my working table:

```
{FLATTEN($A$2:$B$5),FLATTEN(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(REPT(concat($C$2:$C$5," "),2)," ")))}
```

[image]

Then the two conditions are:

```
MATCH(H1:H3,FLATTEN($A$2:$B$5),0),0)
```

or

```
MOD(MATCH(H1:H3,FLATTEN($A$2:$B$5),1),2)=1
```

This will return TRUE if the key timestamp matches any of the timestamps, or if it returns an odd position (1,3,5... etc).

If the condition returns true, this formula will lookup the employee name:

```
    VLOOKUP(H1:H3,
           {FLATTEN($A$2:$B$5),FLATTEN(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(REPT(concat($C$2:$C$5," "),2)," ")))}
           ,2,TRUE
           )
```

else it will return `BLANK`.

**Sample Output:**

[image]

Comment: Please let me know if this solution works for you.